# How to delay a relay closing?

Tags: relay, remote-control, delay, timing, switching

I have a situation where I'd like to delay the closing of an off the shelf relay by ~5 seconds. Assuming it is a 5V coil, and switching 12 V, I'd like the following:

t 0:00: 5v applied to input, relay switch open.
t 0:05: coil closed, relay switch closes.

I think some simple RC network may do the trick, but I'm struggling to imagine the right configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, a RC does the trick, old stuff relay control boxes were doing this way, but I guess not for 5 seconds, it's quite long delay.

Comment: Off the shelf a "time delay relay" of the "on delay" flavor would do it. Or you can build something based on a timer, which is essentially an RC with some help.

Answer (score 6):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faZqf3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A CMOS schmitt trigger 40106 or 4093 (check the numbers) would work for this.

- Pick a reasonable value for C1 - 10uF, say.
- Calculate R so that R * C = 5 s.
- When the input goes high C1 will charge up. At about 2/3 of supply voltage NOT1 output will switch low and NOT2 will switch high. Q1 will turn on and the relay will pull in.
- D1 allows instant reset by discharging C1 when input goes low. It may need addition of a resistor to limit the current to whatever's driving the circuit.
- D2 protects Q1 when RLY1 is switched off.

Comment: Good answer. Not all thgose inverters are Schmitt AFAIR. Schmitt includes 74x14, CD40106, ... . This sort of circuit works very well.

Comment: +1. I agree with Russell if you need a one-off and can trim R1 or C1 to compensate for the variation of NOT1's threshold voltage.  Otherwise, I'd suggest you use a voltage comparator to turn Q1 ON and OFF where the trim will not be nearly as severe.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot guys. Seems simple enough to implement. Appreciate it.